# Can not get data from table from parse in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working with parse here is the image of my app![parse app image][1]

now I am tried a lot to get latitude and longitude from GPSLocation table but I can not get data.I added permissions do it as mentioned in parse documentation but still I can not get data here is my code.

```html
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GPsLocation");

                query.getInBackground("wYo1DfMw0g", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nothing found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // object will be your game score
                        } else {
                            // something went wrong
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I also tried this sample code

```html
 request.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("GPsLocation");
    query.getInBackground("p3VKhrJPKt", new GetCallback() {
     public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
      if (e == null) {
       String latitude = object.getString("latitude");
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"nothing found"+latitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       // object will be your game score
      } else {
       // something went wrong
      }
     }
    });
```

now please help me for that  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQTu2.png

Answer (score 0):

**try this way may this help you.**

**First to Use initialize method**

**Parse.initialize(context, getString(R.string.parseId),
                getString(R.string.parseSecret));**

```
Parse.initialize(context, getString(R.string.parseId),
            getString(R.string.parseSecret));
    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

**then,**

```
private void getDataFromGpsLocation (){
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("GPsLocation");

    try {
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        for (ParseObject parseobj : ob) {
        // u get your field name 
            Log.e("score" ,""+parseobj.latitude);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```